Merging xarrays keeping attributes
ds = xr.Dataset({})
ds_add = xr.Dataset({
    'nom': xr.DataArray(
    data   = np.random.random((2,2)),   # enter data here
    dims   = ['x', 'y'],
    coords = {"x":[1,2], "y":[1,2]},
    attrs  = {
            'field attrs': 'my field attr'
                }
    )}, 
    attrs  = {
        'array attrs': 'my array attr'
            }
    )
print(ds_add.attrs)
print(ds_add.nom.attrs)

ds = xr.merge([ds, ds_add])

print(ds.attrs)
print(ds.nom.attrs)

Result in:
>{'array attrs': 'my array attr'}

>{'field attrs': 'my field attr'}

>{}

>{'field attrs': 'my field attr'}

How can I keep the attributes through the merger of Xarrays?

We can use: combine_attrs='no_conflicts'
